# responsive "background-image" not automatically resizing with orientation change css iOS

Tags: css, angularjs, responsive-design, orientation

I have an image in the dom that is sized based on the height of the screen. It works perfectly on all browsers and devices (at least all that I'm concerned about), except for Safari iOS 7.

In Safari iOS, the image loads correctly for the given orientation. However, when the orientation changes (portrait to landscape or landscape to portrait) the image doesn't resize based on the new height. (Note that it *does* resize as expected on Android devices.) THEN when you rotate *back* to the original orientation the image does resize, but for the orientation you just changed from - so it's now wrong!

I also noticed that if the image is incorrect and (without changing orientation) I interact with an element on the page which would also render based on the screen height, it loads fine *AND* the image in question is resized to the correct size.

I think what I'd like to do at this point is to force a css reload upon orientation change, unless there is a better solution. Would I need to do this in javascript? or can it be done in the css?

The following is my relevant css:

```
    position: relative;
    height: 90vh;
    z-index: -3;
    bottom: 50px;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-position: 30%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image:image-url("the/path/to/my/image.jpg");
```

*Note: I cannot use jQuery, and this is an angularJS app

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on precisely what you're looking for, but could you use a CSS media query to detect portrait vs. landscape? This way you could perhaps get better precision with your backgrounds when the orientation changes.

```
@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  background-size: auto 100%;
}
@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

Without additional specifics about your issue though, it's hard for me to say, but maybe that might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry that this it's not super clear -- it seems to not to be anything wrong with the code, but rather with Safari iOS. The image resizes on other devices when they change orientation. Safari resizes the image as I want it to, but not _only_ after you interact with the page (where the interaction would change some other css). I, however, would like it to resize the image automatically :/

Comment: The media queries behave exactly like my current code, btw

Comment: Do you have a public example or a fiddle that you could share so we could see the behavior you're describing?